# Accessing notepad from SSH Server

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, terminal, putty

I setup an SSH server in my windows 10 PC using [MobaSSH](https://mobassh.mobatek.net/) Server. I then connected to it using another windows 10 PC using [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download.html) SSH Client (through a local user account in the server). X11-Forwarding is configured on both server and client.

I wanted to access a .txt file in my server. So in the Xterm SSH Client terminal, I moved to the corresponding directory and tried the command:

```
notepad xyz.txt
```

I was expecting the notepad application in the server to open in my terminal. But nothing happened. The terminal looked frozen. Had to apply Ctr+C to exit out. I tried Putty with X11 forwarding. Still didn't work.

Is it not possible to access server's windows applications through this method ??? I found success with Linux's SSH server. I could open applications like gvim. But in case of Windows, its not working. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows does not use X11 for its graphical interface, so it's natural that X11 forwarding would not work.

*(However, you can use this for X11-based programs that were ported from Linux and are running through Cygwin, or Interix, or through Windows Subsystem for Linux. Basically, if a program would need Xwin/Xming, then it would work with X11 forwarding too.)*

There is no option for running native Windows graphical programs directly through SSH – instead you need to connect using either "Remote Desktop" (mstsc) or various third-party programs like VNC.

*(In general, noticeable difference is that Remote Desktop attaches to a specific user's desktop in exclusive mode, while third-party programs instead attach to the whole screen in shared/mirrored mode.)*

Remote Desktop can also be configured for RemoteApp, which allows connecting to individual apps (multi-window) instead of the whole desktop. It doesn't require Windows Server, but it does require each app to be pre-configured for this.

Unfortunately I haven't heard of any Windows programs which would intercept individual windows and "forward" them through X11, but it would certainly be cool.

Comment: Hmm...Thanks for the info. Was experimenting.  Thought it would be cool if I can run some big programs like MATLAB through SSH from the server  ;-(

Comment: Why won't it upen notepad on the server? But calc works.